# Incident angle and refracted angle

Tags: optics

> [image]

I came across this picture while studying about Huygens' principle and Laws of Refraction.In my book I saw that it is mentioned $\theta_1$ is the incident angle and $\theta_2$ is the refracted angle but I could not understand why this should be.Maybe I could not understand this as I am familiar with ray diagrams where the normal is perpendicular to the surface whereas here the green lines are at $90^0$ to the incident rays.

So,I cannot understand which and why is the incident ray and the refracted ray.Please explain which and why is the incident angle and refracted angle.

Thanks for any help!!

Note-The light rays are traveling from medium air to water.The surfaces are separated the blue line.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that's confusing, and that $\theta_2$ is just plain wrong. I've always seen it explained with the normal perpendicular to the surface, just like you say, and exactly as drawn in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law  But note that this gives the same $\theta_1$ as in your drawing. But the way you've drawn your drawing, $\theta_2=\theta_1$, period, independent of the refracted ray. Check your textbook again. I think maybe you transcribed its illustration wrong. It's hard to believe such a blatant blunder slipped by the editors and made it into print.

Comment: What @john-forkosh said. Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_incidence or any number of other sources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....you are right...I did not transcribe it properly....

Answer (score 2):

The green lines are wave fronts, not normal lines. You can think of the green lines as crests of the wave. That's why they're always perpendicular to the ray. Contrast this with normal lines, which are perpendicular to the *surface*.

You're right, incident and refracted angles are always measured between the ray and the normal to the surface. This turns out to be the same angle as measuring between the wave front and the surface.

Your drawing is a little wrong though. After the light wave gets refracted, the wave fronts need to be bent along with the rays.

[image]